# Stacking Windows environment variables

Tags: windows, windows-registry, environment-variables

Is it possible to "stack" Windows environment variables such as,

```
"RUBY_PATH" = "C\ruby\bin"
"PYTHON_PATH" = "C:\python332"
"PROGRAMMING_PATH" = "%RUBY_PATH%;%PYTHON_PATH%"
"Path" = ...;%PROGRAMMING_PATH%'"
```

I can do it on Linux nodes, but so far, no luck on Windows nodes. Anything I'm not doing right?

Comment: What do you mean stack? You can have multiple environment variables, and each environment variable can have multiple paths... You want to expand environment variables in another variable?

Comment: Well, the example above shows me making two environment variables, then assigning them to one, and then putting that variable into the regular path variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not, Windows does it out of the box:

[image]

I can't say I would personally use it very often, because of the risk of goofing a path up and the not very friendly interface for it. But it looks possible.

Comment: That works, but I'm doing it multiple times, so Path would contain my PROGRAMMING_PATH, and PROGRAMMING_PATH would then contain the other two paths, RUBY_PATH and PYTHON_PATH.

Comment: I believe it will work, but more as a byproduct than as a desired parameter of the design of the env variables. If you want to use %variable% as another variable it would be a good idea (algorithm-wise) to have a good recursive function rather than a predictably broken one... Ultimately you might just have to try it once.

Comment: So far, I'm not having much luck. I am able to do as you said in your answer, but more than 2 levels. I can just use a REGEX to clean up my additions like `/\%RUBY_PATH\%/''/`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily from the command line:

```
SET RUBY_PATH=C:\Ruby\Bin
SET PYTHON_PATH=C:\Python332
SET PROGRAMMING_PATH=%RUBY_PATH%;%PYTHON_PATH%
SET PATH=%PATH%;%PROGRAMMING_PATH%
```

If you are setting these values directly in the registry, you will need to use the **REG_EXPAND_SZ** data type for the ones that need to be expanded. That is, for the variables that contain other variables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`cmd` or batch file:

```
set
```

`wmic`:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT get Name, VariableValue, UserName | more
```

or

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT get * | more
```

`powershell`:

```
powershell gci env: | more
```

WSH:

```
ReadEnv2.vbs | more
```

ReadEnv2.vbs:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment
WScript.Echo "WINDIR=" & WshEnv.Item("WINDIR")  & vbCrLf &_
                                                  vbCrLf

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "Environment System:"              & vbCrLf &_ 
"..............................................."
For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("System")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Environment User:"       & vbCrLf &_ 
"..............................................."
For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("User")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Environment Volatile:"   & vbCrLf &_ 
"..............................................."
For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("Volatile")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next
WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Environment Process:"    & vbCrLf &_ 
"..............................................."
For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("Process")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on how you're setting the environment variables. In the command prompt, you can do this:

```
set a=C:
set b=%a%\Users
set c=%b%\Thomas
cd %c%
```

because environment variables get expanded immediately.

But you can't do that:

```
set c=%b%\Thomas
set b=%a%\Users
set a=C:
cd %c%
```

On the other hand side it works if you define environment variables via the environment variables dialog and then start a command prompt. It also works in a C# program, when set up in that dialog and then queried by

```
string c = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("c");
```